# Changing raster plot break values text using R

Tags: raster, r, plot

I have the following R code that generates a plot.

```
b <- c(0,30,60,90,120,150,180)
rast <- raster("study.area.accessibility.tif")
r <- clamp(rast, 0, 180) 

plot(r, 
     col=topo.colors(length(b)), 
     breaks = b
     )
```

[image]

I want that last break's text to be technically accurate.
That is, instead of 180, I want it to be 180+ or >180.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set `lab.breaks` along with `breaks`.

```
# please ignore this part ###
library(raster)
rast = raster(nrow= 40, ncol= 50)
values(rast) = (1:ncell(rast))/10
# ------------------------###

r <- clamp(rast, 0, 180)

b <- c(0,30,60,90,120,150,180)
lab_b <- c("0","30","60","90","120","150","180+")  # labels for the break

plot(r, 
     col=topo.colors(length(b)), 
     breaks = b,
     lab.breaks = lab_b                             # lab.breaks
)
```

[image]